# How can I tell if an Expando subclass has a property defined?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm creating an app that I want to have an expandable set of properties (each a RatingProperty) I also want to validate that any dynamic properties are of the RatingProperty type.

In the Expando documentation it says:

> Tip: If you want to validate a dynamic property value using a Property class, you can instantiate the Property class and call its validate() method on the value.

So if I want to validate a dynamic property I need to know what the class's non-dynamic properties are. How can I ask my class what it's defined properties are?

I've considered creating a class method that takes a string and returns true if that string is in a list of property names that I create and maintain, but it seems like a hack. I've searched the Google for tips, but haven't had any luck.

Thanks,
Pat

Comment: It helps if you tag your posts with the language that's applicable.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more research (damn you lazyweb!) I've found a solution that I think is acceptable:

A dynamic property can't be of a db subclassed property type. Thus, there are two distinct steps that must be taken. First you need to create an instance of your property class and validate your value:

```
test = db.RatingProperty()
if test.validate(valueToSave):
    #do your thing
```

Next you need to check if the property you want to save is a declared property:

```
if valueToSaveKey not in myObject.properties():
    #if not save it as desired
    myObject.valueToSaveKey = valueToSave
```

The down side here is that the value you save isn't stored as the property type you want.

Comment: The line above that reads:  
    myObject.valueToSaveKey = valueToSave
Should read:
    myObject.__setattr__(valueToSaveKey, valueToSave)

Comment: Probably better to edit your answer next time - this way, people who read the answer only (and that happens more often then you would think :)) don't skip possibly important details from the comments.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_properties

db.Model has methods to find out all the properties on an instance.

The class exposes a list of Property objects: db.Model.properties()

The instance exposes the dynamic names only: instance.dynamic_properties()

You want to loop through the list and build Property objects, and run p.validate().

```
for p_name in instance.dynamic_properties():
    p = db.RatingProperty()
    p.validate() # raises BadValueError, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but if you have a list of properties  you expect to find, why not just use a standard db.Model, instead of an Expando? You can add additional properties to a Model class, as long as you either provide a default or don't make them required.

Comment: I have a list of properties that I know I want to save and an undetermined amount of properties that I know will be of a certain type.  
When I try to add a property I want to first check to see if it's a declared property and, if not, validate that it's value is of the type required.

Comment: But are the 'undetermined' properties being added at runtime, or simply in later revisions of the app? If the former, you could use an ArrayProperty. If the latter, just add them as new properties.

Comment: If you place them in an array you can't filter based on their value. I've considered simply adding properties to the model, but I'm not convinced that it would be easier that way.

Comment: You can filter based on their value, but only based on the value of one at a time. I'm still not clear on your exact requirements. Do you know at runtime what the (current) set of possible properties is?

Comment: Users can set the value of many different properties, though none are required, and there is no sensible default for them. I have a group of suggested properties to edit, though I envision user being able to add properties that they feel are appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite easy!

[ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) implements `(IDictionary<String, Object>)` so you just need to do this :

```
 dynamic person = new ExpandoObject();
 person.FirstName = "Barack";
 person.LastName = "Obama"

 (((IDictionary<String, Object>)person).Keys  
    => { "FirstName", "LastName" }

 (((IDictionary<String, Object>)person).ContainsKey("FirstName")  
    => true
```

Note: You need to explicitly cast to `(IDictionary<string, object>` because ExpandoObject explicitly implements this interface - and the instance itself doesn't have `ContainsKey()` or `Keys`.

Don't expect this method to work with all dynamic objects - just ExpandoObject and anything else that implements this interface.